# Is there a non-constant function $f$ such that $f(n) - 1 = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, ideals, ring-homomorphism

So I've been given rings $R = Map(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ and $S = (a_{n})_{n \geq 0}$ such that $a_{n} \in \mathbb{R}$ and the ring homomorphism

$$
\phi: R \rightarrow S\\
f \rightarrow (f(n))_{n}
$$

And an ideal for the ring homomorphism $I = \{f \in R | f(n) = 0 \text{ for all } n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ and a constant function $\mathbf{1}: x \mapsto 1$

I need to find a non-constant function $f$ such that $f + I = \mathbf{1} + I$.
I understand that this means that I need to find a function such that $f - \mathbf{1} \in I$. And that in simpler terms that it means I need a non-constant function $f$ such that $f(n) - 1 = 0 \text{ for all } n \in \mathbb{N}$ but I can't think of any such function that isn't constant.

Comment: That would imply $f(n)=1~~\forall n$, in other words $f$ is a constant function.

Comment: Unsure about your first paragraph2, but $\cos(2\pi n)-1$ has zeros for $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: @Sal Thanks, I hadn't thought of transforming an oscillating function!